# get available room based on priority and booking data

Tags: javascript

I want to identify that selected booking time is available in one room or in multiple rooms based on priorities?

Like I have booking start time as **10:00** and booking end time as **12:00**,
now room1 is booked for `["11:00-12:00", "12:00-13:00". "13:00-14:00"]`,
room2 is booked for `["12:00-13:00"]` and room3 is booked for `["12:00-13:00"]`

As per the booking time and room booked time `10:00` to `12:00` is not available in **room1** but **room1** is available for `10:00-11:00` and **room2** is available for `10:00-12:00` but I want to give priorities per room number like first I need to fill **room1** then **room2** then **room3**, so I want to book time `10:00-11:00` in **room1** and `11:00-12:00` in **room2**. so how to identify that based on my priority booking time is available consecutive or it was in two different rooms?

If room1 is booked for 10:00-12:00 then it should check for room2 if room2 is available for 10:00-12:00 then it should return true but same case happened with room2 like ubove with room1 then we should go and check for room3

**PS:** I dont know how to check for time slots 
So, I tried this:

```js
var bookingTime = ["10:00-12:00"]
var bookedTime = {
  "room1": ["11:00-12:00", "12:00-13:00", "13:00-14:00"],
  "room2": ["12:00-13:00"],
  "room3": ["12:00-13:00"]
}

function isBooked(bookingTime, bookedTime) {
  //Convert the start and end times to integers - se we can compare easily
  var bookingStartInt = parseInt(bookingTime.split('-')[0].replace(':', '')); //Produces int 1000
  var bookingEndInt = parseInt(bookingTime.split('-')[1].replace(':', '')); //Produces int 1000

  return Object.keys(bookedTime).some(aRoom => {
    return bookedTime[aRoom].every(aSlot => {
      //Convert each slot to start and end integers
      var slotStartInt = parseInt(aSlot.split('-')[0].replace(':', ''));
      var slotEndInt = parseInt(aSlot.split('-')[1].replace(':', ''));

      //Compare if booking time overlaps with the current time slot
      return !(bookingStartInt < slotStartInt && bookingEndInt <= slotStartInt || bookingStartInt >= slotEndInt && bookingEndInt > slotEndInt);
    })
  })
}

console.log(isBooked(bookingTime[0], bookedTime));
```

Comment: question,
can it only be booked an hour at a time, like from 10:00 - 11:00 and not from 10:30-11:15 or something like that?
also what did you mean by  I have booking start time as 10:00 and booking end time as 12:00, does it mean bookings are from 10:00 - 00: 00?

Comment: It can be booked as 10:30-11:15,.. and start time= "10:00" and endtime="12:00" that means i selected ["10:00-12:00"] time slot for booking.

Comment: You should keep your time intervals as Date objects - not strings. It will be much easier for you to do computations. The check for an overlap is `Math.max(0,timeInterval_1.end.getTime() - timeInterval_1.begin.getTime() - Math.max(0,timeInterval_1.end.getTime() - timeInterval_2.end.getTime()) - Math.max(0,timeInterval_2.begin.getTime() - timeInterval_1.begin.getTime()))`